# Why every time I run gitk from a Mac OS X Terminal it opens in background?

Tags: macos, git

Every time I run `gitk` from a Mac OS X Terminal it opens in background.
In other words, `gitk` is always shown behind the Terminal window.

Actually, `gitk` is the only tool manifesting this strange behavior. `gitx`, for example, correctly opens in foreground.

I tried with 3 different macs, all with OS X Lion and all of them have this problem. Strangely, googling I wasn't able to find any info about this.

I found an [old post](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-Force-gitk-as-the-forground-process-when-it-starts-up-on-Mac-OS-X-td2257957.html) about a guy with the same problem, but I guess it's not the same root cause since the post itself claims the bug was fixed in 2009.

Answer (score 0):

In [another SU thread](https://superuser.com/questions/611915/mac-os-x-login-item-without-terminal-window) they suggest:

1. Create a one-line AppleScript:

   `do shell script "/Users/me/dir/executable"`
2. Save As Application "MyScript.app" (without Startup Screen)